# how to get the string length and display from webservies in ios

Tags: ios

i want to get the string  length from webservies and display full text for button title

my webservies: val like this

```
sub_category_name = Barbell
sub_category_name = Kettlebell
sub_category_name = Resistance Bands;
```

i want to display these names.. with full text.. how to do that..and assign that name to one button.

Comment: your question is not clear. you are talking about a web services (that returns key/value-pairs I assume?!), is it in JSON format? then you should use some JSON parser.

Comment: show the full result what u get from JSON,

Comment: hi!! i am saying i want to display the  sub_category_name from web serves. i show in top. that name value some times get more values(that means it make more than 10 letter)on that time i can't show the full name. how to i display the full name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculating string height in iOS

```
 UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14]; //use your font details
 CGRect new = [sub_category_name boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(button.width, 999) options:NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font} context:nil];//use your max height float value instead of 999
 CGSize size= new.size;
 button.frame = CGRectMake(button.frame.origin.x,button.frame.origin.y,button.frame.size.width,size.height);
```